# Rational behind warning/error behaviour from calling __host__ or __device__ functions from __host__ __device__ function

Tags: cuda

I am wondering why a call to a `__host__` function from a `__host__ __device__` function gives only a compilation warning, but a call to a `__device__` function from a `__host__ __device__` function gives a compilation error.

Is there any good reason for that?

```cpp
__host__ void hst() {}
__device__ void dev() {}

__host__ __device__ void func() {
  hst();  // gives a compile warning
  dev();  // gives a compile error
}

int main() {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down the code you provided:

- In the first case, you call the `__host__` function from the function defined for both `__device__` and `__host__` memory. It throws a warning message during compilation because you are trying to call into a host memory from the GPU memory. It does not explicitly throws an error because CUDA was designed for the joint execution of CPU-GPU in an application, and honestly, it's just a way the compiler functions.
- In the second case, you are calling the `__devie__` function to the function that might also be initiated by the `__host__` memory. It throws an error because it expects only the `__device__` or `__global__` memory function calls.

**EDIT**: The reason behind it is CUDA does not allow the `__host__ __device__` to launch as a kernel. If you want to call a `__device__` function, you must call via a `__global__` memory. Let's see with the help of an example-

```cpp
#include <iostream>

__host__ void hst(int* a) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        a[i] = a[i] + 1;
    }
}

__device__ void dev(int* a) {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if (i < 3) {
        a[i] = a[i] + 1;
    }
}

__host__ __device__ void func(int* a) {
    hst(a);     // works but shows a warning from the compiler
    // dev(a);  // throws error; calling the device + host, doesn't work
}

__global__ void function(int* a) {
    // hst(a);  // throws error; cannot call __host__ from device
    func(a);    // works; call to __host__ __device__
    dev(a);     // works; call to __device__
}

int main() {
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    func(a);

    int size = 3 * sizeof(int);
    int *a_d;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&a_d, size);
    cudaMemcpy(a_d, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    // func<<1, 3>>>(a_d);  // throws error; cannot call __device__ directly from the host memory
    function<<<1, 3>>>(a_d);
    cudaMemcpy(a, a_d, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(a_d);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it's clear now :)

Comment: What do you mean by *It does not explicitly throw an error because CUDA was designed to join the CPU-GPU execution of an application.*